# array only pushes first element

Tags: typescript

For some reason, the chordMidiNumbers function isn't working correctly on iOS Chrome. The expected result would be midiArray at least contains 2 or many elements for Howlerjs to play the audio. However, when I tested it on iOS device (iPhone and iPad), the console prints out the first note of the chord and never reaches the return statement. Any help will be greatly appreciated. (Edit: for our project, we uses tonal js to convert notes into midi numbers)

Here is the actual code:

```
 /**
     * Given a chord object, return the midi numbers of the notes in the chord
     * @param {any} chordDetails - The chord details object that is returned from the getChordDetailsFromChord function.
     * @returns The midi numbers of the notes in the chord.
     */

    /*
    Example:
    if app plays C2 Major chord

    chordDetails = { ... , {"chordDetails":"note","chord":{"type":"major","tonic":"C"}}}

//This is what we had before
const chordMidiNumbers = chordNotes.map((noteName: any) => {
  return note(noteName).midi;
});
    */
    const chordMidiNumbers = (
      chordDetails: any,
      additionOctave: number = 0
    ) => {
      const type = chordDetails.chordFormat.chord.type;
      // type = "major"
      const chordNotes = getChordNotesFromChord(chordDetails.chordFormat);
      // chordNotes = ["C2", "E2", "G2"]

      let midiArray: Array<number> = [];
      const customOctave = 12 * additionOctave;
      let tempMidi: number;
      for (let i = 0; i < chordNotes.length; i++) {
        let item = chordNotes[i];
        if (type !== "major" && type !== "minor" && type !== "7") {
          item += 2; //reformatting notes so it can be translated into midi numbers, e.g C+2 = C2
        }
        tempMidi = note(item)?.midi || 0;
        console.log(`tMidi:${tempMidi}`) //36 for C2, 40 for E2, 43 for G2
        if (tempMidi === 0) continue;

        if (midiArray.length === 0) {
          midiArray.push(tempMidi + customOctave);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(midiArray));
        } else {
          if (type === "P8") {
            midiArray.push(tempMidi + 12 + customOctave);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(midiArray));
            continue;
          }
          if (midiArray.at(-1)! > tempMidi + customOctave) {
            midiArray.push(tempMidi + 12 + customOctave);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(midiArray));
          } else {
            midiArray.push(tempMidi + customOctave);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(midiArray));
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(midiArray);
      return midiArray;
    };
```

Expected Outputs:

```
tMidi: 36
[36]
tMidi: 40
[36, 40]
tMidi: 43
[36, 40, 43]
//plays the audio
(3) [36, 40, 43]

//F Major chord
tMidi: 41
[41]
tMidi: 45
[41, 45]
tMidi: 36
[41, 45, 48]
//plays the audio
(3) [41, 45, 48]
```

Actual Outputs:

```
tMidi: 36
[36]
tMidi: 40
//no audio being played

tMidi: 41
[41]
tMidi: 45
//no audio being played
```

Comment: possibly your use of `Array.at()`? Also you're writing four conditions for only 2 different possible values, perhaps simplifying your logic will help point out the error.

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the advice, issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Array.at()` isn't supported on iOS Chrome (Thanks to pilchard). Program returns fully functional when I replaced `Array.at()` with `[midiArray.length - 1]`